# mkdir command not found?

Tags: linux, perl, bioinformatics

I think I messed up the PATH. I was installing Bioperl and tried to changed path. The correct code should be:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/bin:$PATH
$ export PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/site/bin:$PATH
$PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/bin:$PATH
$PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/site/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

--
But I did something stupid and what I typed is attached.  Although Bioperl is installed, the ls or mkdir command are not working any more.[image]

Comment: logout and login again.  All those `export` commands will be forgotten

Comment: `:export PATH` is wrong, as the colon attaches `export` to the `PATH` variable. you probably want a semi-colon `;` instead there

Comment: Hi rongrong, I wondered whether you would consider accepting my answer? If you think it could use improvements, please give me feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you ran `export PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/` it replaced your entire previous path with that one single directory.

Subsequent attempts to "do the right thing" were now using the new path, so when you ran `PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/bin:$PATH`, what that did was update the `PATH` variable to contain the following string:

```
/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/bin:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/
```

To recover from this situation, you have a few options:

### 1. Explicitly set the path to be what you want

Run something like the following (edit according to your requirements:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.26/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

### 2. Source your bashrc or bash_profile to reset the environment

You probably have your default path set in either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. Let's assume it's in `~/.bashrc`, then you can reset it like so:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Which is short for:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

### 3. Start a new shell session

It might be simplest to just abandon the current session and start over. Close the terminal and open a new one; or go into a new shell inside the current terminal by running `/bin/bash`

Comment: I tried the #3 way, but it turned out I dont have .bashrc folder, lol. #2 way works for me! Thank you so much.